# Proper subgroup is cyclic if $|G|=p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let G be a group with |G| = p^2, where p is prime. Show that every proper subgroup of G is cyclic.

Proof: Let H be a proper subgroup of G where |G| = p^2 and p is prime. Then |H| divides |G| by Lagrange's Theorem. So |H| = 1, p, or p^2. Since H is proper, then |H| does not equal |G|. So |H| = 1 or p.

I do not know if I am correct or where to go from this point if I am correct.

Comment: If $|H| = 1$, it's pretty easy. If $|H| = p$, and $h \in H$ is not the identity, what's $|h|$?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct so far. Now you need to show that every group of prime order or of order 1 is cyclic. The order 1 case is trivial. For the prime order case, assume it is not cyclic. Then there exists a nontrivial proper subgroup of our subgroup of order p. But Lagrange's theorem says that the order of this subgroup divides p, which means it can't be nontrivial and proper.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, either $|H|=1$ (and there is nothing to prove) or $|H|=p$. In this latter case pick any $h\in H,\;\;h\neq1$ and consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $h$, namely $\langle h\rangle$.

Clearly $\{1\}\neq\langle h\rangle\le H$, from which it follows that $H$ needs to be $\langle h\rangle$, which is cyclic.